# ExecCommand('copy') doesn't work for all browers

Tags: copy, execcommand

I have a problem with : execCommand('copy');
I used this in my project, but it does not work on all browsers. I want to copy my selection to my clipboard with button. Have you any similar solution for this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Safari 10, it does work for all modern browsers.